# sequential execution of Show with two input streams, one of graphics object and another of characters

Tags: graphics, map

The question is how to sequentially execute Show with two streams of input. The first is graphics object stream and the second is a character stream for supplying labelling for the graphics. I tried

```
ss={{ListPlot[x1]},{ListPlot[x2],...};labelling={aa,bb,cc,dd....};
Map[Show[#1,PlotLabel->StringJoin[#2,"...","..."]]&,{ss,labelling}]
```

Comment: I tried both Map and MapThread to inconsistent results. It became consistent when I put the labelling elements into individual curly brackets, i.e., labelling={{aa},{bb},{cc},(dd)) Wonder why is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html):

```
SeedRandom[1]
{x1, x2, x3, x4} = RandomInteger[100, {4, 30}];

ss = ListPlot /@ {x1, x2, x3, x4}; 

labeling = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"}; 

MapThread[Show[#, PlotLabel -> StringJoin[#2, "...", "..."]] &, {ss, labeling}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) the function `Show[...]` on `Transpose[{ss, labeling}]`:

```
Show[#1, PlotLabel -> StringJoin[#2, "...", "..."]] & @@@ Transpose[{ss, labeling}]
```

> same picture

You can also use `ListPlot[...]` in the first argument of `MapThread`:

```
datasets = {x1, x2, x3, x4};
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange};
joined = {True, False, False, True};

MapThread[ListPlot[#, Joined -> #4, 
   PlotLabel -> StringJoin[#2, "...", "..."], PlotStyle -> #3] &, 
 {datasets, labeling, colors, joined}]
```

[image]

Again, you can `Apply` the function `ListPlot[...]` on  tuples of parameters to get the same result:

```
ListPlot[#, Joined -> #4, 
   PlotLabel -> StringJoin[#2, "...", "..."], PlotStyle -> #3] & @@@ 
 Transpose[{datasets, labeling, colors, joined}]
```

> same picture

Comment: I tried both Map and MapThread to inconsistent results. It became consistent when I put the labelling elements into individual curly brackets, i.e., labelling={{aa},{bb},{cc},(dd))  Wonder why is this the case?